# Nearby Interaction Framework unsupported in iOS 15 with iPhone 13

Tags: ios, swift, wwdc

[image: Image if iPhone 11, 12, 13 (iOS 15.0)]

Hello Devs,
I have been working on **Nearby Interaction** Framework from Apple.
[Download sample project from Apple.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/nearbyinteraction/implementing_interactions_between_users_in_close_proximity)

Since Nearby Interaction Framework works on **Simulator iOS 14 or later**.
But I am unable to run on **iPhone 13 iOS 15.0 Simulator** and getting unsupported Devices Error.
So Does iPhone 13 lacks U1 chip? Or something wrong with Simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a simulator issue; The app works on a real iPhone 13 Pro

Comment: Ohh Really! Did you tried on Simulator?

Comment: Yes, the simulator shows the same message you see